# How to fix " Not found " when refresh page with vue js SPA in Apache Server?

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router

I just deploy my vue js project to apache server. My file `/dist` located in `/var/www/html/dist`. When i visit the page it's work fine. But when i visit in another page and i refresh the page, in browser say 404 Not found. How can i fix this ?

Comment: You are not supplying enough information.  I suspect it has something to do with how you are using vue-router.

Comment: You have not configured your server. What are you expecting? You're serving flat HTML. Your server doesn't know to forward all requests for all URL's to your index page. `/` works because you probably defined an `index`, but all other routes? like `/about-us`? Apache doesn't know about those. Configure it to.

Comment: Yea i use vue-router. in my vue router like this : `export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/detail',
      name: 'detail',
      component: Detail
    } ] });` so how can i configure in server ?

Comment: The answer you seek is in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy oke, but where i should put .htaccess in server? inside `/var/www/html/dist` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a configuration something similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will automatically serve `index.html` file for every request that doesn't have a corresponding static file. You will have to put this `.htaccess` file. The use of `IfModule` is [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/810206/526959).

Comment: Hey @Harshall Patil i just that code in apache in folder `/var/www/html/dist/.htaccess`, in `/dist` folder contain index.html, after that i restart apache but still not working.

Comment: I just fix it, i forget to enable `.htaccess`  in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: 2022 still a valid fix. I was using FallbackResource but with https it didn't seem to work, this solution did. Ubuntu Apache

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have same error, on ubuntu after i install apache.
First i added in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

AllowOverride All

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost test.ru:80>

ServerName www.test.ru
ServerAlias test.ru

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.ru
<Directory /var/www/test.ru>
    #Разрешение на перезапись всех директив при помощи .htaccess
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Then in console activate rewrite module and restart apache

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```